# Multiple Field Values on Separate Page

Tags: 7, views, nodes, entities

I have multiple values for a field in a node, and am displaying only the top 5 using CSS, however, I would like to display the full list of values on a separate page with a, 'View More' link to that page.

My initial reaction would be to create a views page, but how would I associate that view page with a specific node, and then how would I link to that views page from the original node?

The example:

- The main node would be a content type for, 'Author'
- Another content type that get's referenced from Author are, 'Publication'
- The Author's node will display the top 5 Publications and then have a View More link to the full list of publication.

Is there any better way to accomplish this? All thoughts will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Views would be the most common way to do this. I will show you a Display Suite method though.

Install these modules:

[Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) (or any model that can give you extra view modes such as [Entity view modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode)

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7
>   only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

[View Mode Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page)

> Create separate pages for different view modes for a given content
>   type.
>
> On the manage display page for a given content type, you can assign
>   patterns for view modes so that they will become a page at the given
>   path. For instance, if you want to show the teaser at a specific URL,
>   you could do node/%/teaser. If you also use Display Suite or other
>   modules that allow you to create new view modes, you can use these
>   modes to display one or more fields from a node at a separate URL.

[Field multiple limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_multiple_limit)

> This is a simple module that provides settings to limit the number of
>   values to display on fields with multiple values.

[Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)

> Provides additional tokens not supported by core (most notably
>   fields), as well as a UI for browsing tokens.

**Default View Mode:**

On your content type's default view mode activate One Column Display Suite layout and click on the gear next to your multi value field and set it to show the first 5 of the multi value field. Use Display Suite to create a `Code Field` on entities node, with Field code:

`<a href="[current-page:url]/more">Show all</a>`.

Tick Token. Back on the manage display for the default view mode you will now see that field: Show all. Drag it to where you want it displayed

**Show all View Mode:**

Use Display Suite to create an additional View mode. Go to Manage display for the new View mode and set the 'View mode pages' URL pattern to `node/%/all`. Make sure you set the multi value field to show all values.